# Accessing and using the QuickMapServices Plugin externally (outside of QGIS)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, basemap, quickmapservices

I would like to add a OSM Standard Basemap to my project through a python script running in PyCharm, outside of QGIS. Within QGIS, I use QuickMapServices and add an OSM Standard Map but I can not seem to find anywhere how to retrieve the information from this plugin. Ultimately, I would like to know some code from a script that adds a base map to my project. I have tried using the code below but it says it is valid. However, no map appears in my project.

```
    import glob
    import json
    import math
    import os
    import sys
    
    from qgis.core import *
    
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
    from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
    from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
    from qgis.core import QgsApplication
    from qgis.core import QgsProcessingFeedback
    from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
    from qgis._gui import QgsMapCanvas
    
    os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = r'C:\OSGEO4W64\apps\Qt5\plugins'
    os.environ['PATH'] += r';C:\OSGEO4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGEO4W64\apps\Qt5\bin'
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\proj'
    
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/qgis-bin.exe", True)
    qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
    qgs.initQgis()
    
    sys.path.extend([r'C:\OSGEO4W64\apps\qgis\python',r'C:\OSGEO4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages'])
    sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins')
    
    from qgis import processing
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    Processing.initialize()
    QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
    
    # Write your code here to load some layers, use processing
    # algorithms, etc.
    DistInt = {}
    
    # Add Base Map
    urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
    rlayer2 = iface.addRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')
    
    if rlayer2.isValid():
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer2)
    else:
        print('invalid layer')
```

Comment: I have add the lines in my script I have used before adding my base map, above. I have just taken a snippet as my script is over 400 lines long. I have added QgsMapCanvas but not bridge? Thanks.

Comment: Did you create QMainWindow? Where do you define QgsMapCanvas?

Comment: I have not created a QMainWindow. I have only imported QgsMapCanvas from qgis._gui.

Comment: Did you add other layers (shapefile for example) to the project and did they appear?

Comment: Yes, further down the script I have added a QgsRasterLayer and a QgsVectorLayer and they have both appeared in the project and the exported map too. For some reason though, the base map does not appear on the map...

Comment: Integrated your code in a sample I maintain with everything working with your layer https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/f711853e5fb81c746d2a1af0b2a9ecf5 I see at least 1 obvious error: `iface.addRasterLayer` should be `QgsRasterLayer` (adapt import). `iface` not available in standalone application. You may adapt my script to troubleshot your own issue. PS: on Linux so, less environment variables than you

Answer (score 5):

We don't know that the other parts of your code look like. So it is hard to provide a perfect answer. But the followings will give you an idea. It worked for me in the project with GUI.

```
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge

...

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(root, canvas)

...
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a little bit confused on how to implement this into my project, so that I can see the base map within my project? Where in my script would I add this code? Thanks

Comment: The first line to "imports",  the last two lines underneath where you define `QgsMapCanvas`.

Comment: I have added the first line where my imports are and then under my code where I have canvas = QgsMapCanvas(), I have changed the code to self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas() and added the two lines below that. However, it now says that name 'self' is not defined... can I import the module self?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code. Otherwise, it is hard to say something, We don't know how the script file are structured. I thought you use a class, so I added `self`. Try to remove `self`s.

Comment: I have tried to remove self but still no luck unfortunately. Sorry I know it is hard to understand how the script is structured without the full script.

Comment: Please add a minimal working version of your script. You can add pseudo-path.

Comment: Sorry I am quite a basic at python and have only just started using this website. What is a pseudo-path and how can I add one? Thanks

Comment: I mean you don't need to add real file paths to the script if you don't want file names/paths to be displayed here.